# 'png.h' file not found, when included in qt widget project

Tags: c++, qt, libpng

i'm trying to make a QT Widgets project. I have to use a "libpng" library, but i'm having a trouble including it. Here is the config .pro file.

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = coursework2
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \

INCLUDEPATH += $(LIBRARY_SHARE)/libpng/include
LIBS += -L$(LIBRARY_SHARE)/libpng/lib -lpng

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

This is the solution, which worked for lots of people (found it somewhere), but has no result for me. When i try to include it in **main.cpp** file, this error pops up:

```
'png.h' file not found
 #include "png.h"
     ^~~~~~~
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: The first thing I would do is temporarily add this line to your .pro file:  `warning("LIBRARY_SHARE IS "  $$LIBRARY_SHARE)` and then re-run qmake.  That will print to stdout what the LIBRARY_SHARE variable is set to; examine that output to make sure that LIBRARY_SHARE is set to what it should be, such that `$$(LIBRARY_SHARE)/libpng/include/png.h` is a valid path.  (if it isn't, you can manually set LIBRARY_SHARE to what it needs to be set to, at the top of your .pro file)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, yeah, it actually just prints "`Project WARNING: LIBRARY_SHARE IS `" without anything else. But how can i set a  LIBRARY_SHARE variable?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, if i set `LIBRARY_SHARE = $usr/local/lib`, nothing still works.

Comment: I think you probably want to lose the dollar sign, i.e. `LIBRARY_SHARE = /usr/local/lib`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pretty simple. I made a mistake in the root to **"libpng"**.

I had to change my 2 lines of code:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/libpng
```